# Why does my menu become transparent?

Tags: 13.10, menu, transparency

When I check the "about this computer", the pop up menu becomes transparent. This is the image: [image]

also when I right-click the window and choose "change the desktop background", the 'all settings' comes out !!!!
How can I solve it? I have tried restarting the computer, but this doesn't help.

Comment: Are you using a custom theme?

Comment: @LouisMatthijssen  nope, I did not set anything. I just upgrade the system from 13.04 to 13.10. also when I right-click the window and choose "change the desktop background", the 'all settings' comes out !!!!. It seems there is anything wrong. but I cannot fix it

Comment: Try installing gnome-tweak-tool then change theme.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I can't comment (due to lacking reputation) therefore I am answering.  I believe there is actually a `Compiz` bug with your version - you would need to install the missing dependencies - I wish I could remember which dependency.

*hopefully this will get you one step closer to a solution*

Comment: now, you can comment.

Comment: :) - From what I remember with this particular issue was the window manager had no minimize/close buttons or borders.  I remember I had to install some compiz dependencies using the `sudo apt-get install -f` - Although, I can't remember the actual dependency that is missing (*which doesn't really help*).

Comment: nope...it doesn't work.

Comment: OK - first try downloading the Compiz-Fusion `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`.  Then open this and scroll down to **Effects** and then enable the **Window Decoration** option?

Comment: yes. It is enabled

Comment: Hm,I would say then this issue differs from my issue.  Could [this link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2181739) be useful?  I'm not entirely sure of what display manager you're using, theme settings, etc.